# What is the status of Arduino.SE Public Beta

Tags: discussion

Now we've been in Beta for 90 days.

If we take a look at the latest metrics, we are still far from SE expectations on almost all aspects.

[image]

So what's next?

Is the Beta going to be extended (how is that decided and by whom?)

What will happen if the Beta is not extended?

If the Beta is extended, how can we improve Arduino.SE achievements to meet SE expectations?

I know these are several questions in one, but I guess the time has come to take stock of our situation as I believe several people here are wondering the same.

Answer (score 9):

**TL;DR** everything is going to continue as normal.

---

> So what's next?

Nothing special.

> Is the Beta going to be extended (how is that decided and by whom?)

Yes. Sites may stay in beta for 2-3 years before any decisions may be taken. The Community Team reviews every beta site every 2-3 months, and looks for any problems or issues. If there aren't any ominous posts from the CM team, that usually means the site is doing fine, and is progressing towards a graduation.

> What will happen if the Beta is not extended?

This will be a long time away, *if* at all it gets to that.

> If the Beta is extended, how can we improve Arduino.SE achievements to meet SE expectations?

The statistics are not absolute criteria. A site may be kept in beta, even if it meets all the criteria; a site may be launched even if it meets 3/5 of the criteria. The numbers are there just to guide the community on some generic goals. The CM team knows and understands that each site is different, and they look for continuous stable growth, rather a set 3-4 parameters. The graduation process is very fuzzy.

*However*, sites should try to stay in the green on atleast 3 to 4 of the 5 parameters shown on A51.

Comment: Thanks, this looks to be good news! Is there some location on A51 (or elsewhere) where I could find out more about this?

Comment: @jfpoilpret There are a few posts by [Robert](http://meta.arduino.stackexchange.com/users/48/robert-cartaino) around many other metas. You will have to search around to find more. I will link back if I come across anything recent.

Comment: @jfpoilpret I've been watching these parameters for a while now and it looks like things are picking up now. Visits a day is steadily growing - it just went over 500 from `Needs Work` to `Okay`. Great new! Right on!!